# CMake imported targets link order with diamond dependency is not what we expect

Tags: cmake

I'm using Conan for external dependencies, and as such make good use of imported targets in CMake. So much so, that I've stumbled upon a problem that I can't seem to fix.

A minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2 FATAL_ERROR)                                                                                                          
project(test_project VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)                                                                                                      

add_library(IMPORTED::a INTERFACE IMPORTED)                                                                                                              
add_library(IMPORTED::b INTERFACE IMPORTED)                                                                                                              
add_library(IMPORTED::c INTERFACE IMPORTED)                                                                                                              

set_property(TARGET IMPORTED::a PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES a IMPORTED::c)                                                                         
set_property(TARGET IMPORTED::b PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES b IMPORTED::c)                                                                         
set_property(TARGET IMPORTED::c PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES c)                                                                                     

add_executable(test_link main.cpp)                                                                                                                       
target_link_libraries(test_link IMPORTED::a)                                                                                                             
target_link_libraries(test_link IMPORTED::b)
```

In this case, both libraries a and b depend on library c. The link order of test_link should thus be something like -la -lb -lc. Instead, VERBOSE=1 make shows us that this is not happening:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable test_link
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test_link.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ccache  g++    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/test_link.dir/main.cpp.o  -o test_link -la -lc -lb
```

c is correctly pulled in as a dependency of a, but b is linked in afterwards, and G++ will not resolve the symbols from b in c.

In the actual project A and B are Protobuf and OpenCV, and C is Zlib. When linking as CMake does now, the compiler justly complains that OpenCV is missing some symbols that it should find in zlib.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in CMake? And finally, how can I fix this ?

Comment: `G++ will not resolve the symbols from b in c.` - For resolve this, you need to tell CMake that "c" depends on "b". There is no such dependency in your current `CMakeLists.txt`.